# Information Needed: Cross border transaction classifications in Stripe

Tags: node.js, json, stripe-payments

I'm building an app with Stripe payment. While making an API to create a **custom** account with `business_type:` `company`, I added every necessary details that's was shown but my test account is still not active. When I hovered my mouse over the `restricted` box, it shows- **Information Needed**: Cross border transaction classifications.
I scrolled down to check if I can find some detailed explanation, I noticed these 2 fields are the only ones missing:
[image: Stripe Screenshot]

So then I called an API to fetch the details of that particular account and noticed those 2 fields there and they were both set as active:

[image: API response screenshot]

What seems to be keeping my account from being active then? Every other fields appear to be be set. Here's the full response in case it's required.

```
{
"id": "acct_1mkMtESxc2tCnZao",
"object": "account",
"business_profile": {
    "mcc": null,
    "name": "Abin's Shop",
    "product_description": null,
    "support_address": null,
    "support_email": null,
    "support_phone": null,
    "support_url": null,
    "url": null
},
"business_type": "company",
"capabilities": {
    "card_payments": "active",
    "transfers": "active"
},
"charges_enabled": true,
"company": {
    "address": {
        "city": "Trivandrum",
        "country": "IN",
        "line1": "address line 1",
        "line2": null,
        "postal_code": "695044",
        "state": "KL"
    },
    "directors_provided": false,
    "executives_provided": false,
    "gst_id_number": "ADECF1234A",
    "id_number": "U67190TN2019PTC965874",
    "name": "Abin's Shop",
    "owners_provided": false,
    "pan": "000000000",
    "registration_number": "U67190TN2019PTC965874",
    "tax_id_provided": true,
    "vat_id_provided": true,
    "verification": {
        "document": {
            "back": null,
            "details": null,
            "details_code": null,
            "front": null
        }
    }
},
"country": "IN",
"created": 1663743771,
"default_currency": "inr",
"details_submitted": false,
"email": "abi@mail.com",
"external_accounts": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "ba_1LkSOISEc2JCnZZXhIUsFI9x",
            "object": "bank_account",
            "account": "acct_1LkMxESEc2JCnZZX",
            "account_holder_name": "Abin Gomez",
            "account_holder_type": null,
            "account_type": null,
            "available_payout_methods": [
                "standard"
            ],
            "bank_name": "HDFC BANK - BANGALORE - JAYANAGAR",
            "country": "IN",
            "currency": "inr",
            "default_for_currency": true,
            "fingerprint": "127HD5Pr7OCyi08W",
            "last4": "6789",
            "metadata": {},
            "routing_number": "HDFC0000261",
            "status": "new"
        }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/accounts/acct_1LkMxESEc2JCnZZX/external_accounts"
},
"future_requirements": {
    "alternatives": [],
    "current_deadline": null,
    "currently_due": [],
    "disabled_reason": null,
    "errors": [],
    "eventually_due": [],
    "past_due": [],
    "pending_verification": []
},
"metadata": {},
"payouts_enabled": false,
"requirements": {
    "alternatives": [],
    "current_deadline": 1664434973,
    "currently_due": [
        "company.business_cross_border_transaction_classifications"
    ],
    "disabled_reason": "requirements.past_due",
    "errors": [],
    "eventually_due": [
        "company.business_cross_border_transaction_classifications"
    ],
    "past_due": [
        "company.business_cross_border_transaction_classifications"
    ],
    "pending_verification": []
},
"settings": {
    "bacs_debit_payments": {},
    "branding": {
        "icon": null,
        "logo": null,
        "primary_color": null,
        "secondary_color": null
    },
    "card_issuing": {
        "tos_acceptance": {
            "date": null,
            "ip": null
        }
    },
    "card_payments": {
        "decline_on": {
            "avs_failure": false,
            "cvc_failure": false
        },
        "statement_descriptor_prefix": null,
        "statement_descriptor_prefix_kana": null,
        "statement_descriptor_prefix_kanji": null
    },
    "dashboard": {
        "display_name": null,
        "timezone": "Etc/UTC"
    },
    "payments": {
        "statement_descriptor": null,
        "statement_descriptor_kana": null,
        "statement_descriptor_kanji": null
    },
    "payouts": {
        "debit_negative_balances": false,
        "schedule": {
            "delay_days": 5,
            "interval": "daily"
        },
        "statement_descriptor": null
    },
    "sepa_debit_payments": {}
},
"tos_acceptance": {
    "date": 1663764645,
    "ip": "123.88.44.197",
    "user_agent": ""
},
"type": "custom"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since your data shows this is an Indian account, this is likely related to the additional information related to India and Connect:

https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments
https://support.stripe.com/questions/transaction-purpose-code-for-stripe-account-in-india
https://support.stripe.com/questions/accepting-international-payments-from-stripe-accounts-in-india

I'd suggest reaching out to Stripe support at https://support.stripe.com for additional help with account verification.